# Can you back date Deployments

Tags: newrelic

In New relic I have just come across the deployments section and wonder if I can back date a deployment we did today? I cannot see any argument I can send in the POST to the API.

Also when testing the deployments on a dev environment. The second time I sent a deployment to the API it failed with 403 error. I assume this is due to how close the deploys were sent. So what is the limit to how frequent I can send deploys?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

New Relic deployment markers will post a deployment line on your New Relic graphs at the time when the POST is sent. Right now, there is not a way to specify that this time should be earlier or later than the time the POST is actually sent. You could always add a descriptive note to your POST indicating the actual time of the deployment, but that won't change the placement of the line in your graphs on your New Relic UI (see http://newrelic.github.io/newrelic_api/NewRelicApi/Deployment.html). If you want further information on this, you can always talk with support by opening a ticket at support.newrelic.com.

In terms of the 403 error you received, this is usually due to an invalid or missing API key or other problem with the way the query was written. If you're sending several back-to-back deployment POSTs in the same minute, it's possible that our servers would see this as erroneous as well. I would suggest opening up a support ticket at support.newrelic.com so we can dig into your particular situation in more depth.

Comment: There's a feature idea for optional timestamp https://discuss.newrelic.com/t/feature-idea-add-timestamp-option-for-deployments/4546 - feel free to vote if you need that!